# Problem with column widths

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I'm trying to create a table that has 2 rows: 25% and 75% of the `\textwidth`

I also want the left column to be bold and right aligned by default. The second column is also right aligned.

Now I want some cells in the left column to be left aligned, I searched for this and this should be how to do it: `\multicolumn{1}{l}{Left}`

This is my code with some dummy rows

```
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedleft\hsize=.5\hsize\bfseries}X|>{\raggedleft\hsize=1.5\hsize}X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Left} & Right\\
\hline
Right & Right\\
\hline
Right & Right\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

But I'm having some problems:

1. It's not correctly 25 and 75 %, the last column ends too quick.
2. It's not compiling, I get errors about my alignment tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there: Add the command `\arraybackslash` to the specification of the second `X` column:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedleft\hsize=.5\hsize\bfseries}X|
    >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=1.5\hsize}X|}
```

It doesn't hurt (but it's not essential) to add `\arraybackslash` to the specification of the first column as well.

Separately, be sure to write

```
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Left}
```

rather than just `\multicolumn{1}{l}{Left}` if you want vertical bars to the left and right of that cell.

Comment: Thanks! Now that I saw 25 and 75%, I think 35 and 65% should be better. What do I need for hsize then, 0.35 and 1.65? Also, is it possible to automically break text if it leaves the column?

Comment: Choose 0.7 and 1.3: The two `\hsize` numbers have to add up to the number of columns, which is 2 in the present case. To verify: 0.7/2=0.35=35% and 1.3/2=0.65=65%. :-) Yes, the `X` column type will wrap text automatically if it's wider than the column it's assigned to.

Comment: Indeed, 0.7 and 1.3 works and looks better. The text in the second column goes out of my page though, instead of wrapping.

Comment: @Aaron - That's odd. Please double-checke that the second column is defined as `>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=1.3\hsize}X`. Separately, what's the nature of the text you have in the second column: Is it something, e.g., a long URL string, that LaTeX may not want to break up into shorter chunks?

Comment: Yup, it was like that. Anyway, I added more text to other rows and some other things, and now its working. Don't know why it didn't work before. Anyway, thanks for your answers!